# How does Joomla route to the controller method on submitting the form?

Tags: php, forms, joomla, form-submit

In a case where the form action is set to something like:

```
action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_test&layout=edit&id='.(int) $this->item->id); ?>"
```

and the form contains and hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="task" value="testctrl.save" />
```

How does joomla route to the controller method?

I would understand if it had the task in the form action, but I can't see how it picks up the task from the hidden input in order to route to the appropriate method in the `testctrl` controller method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not that complicated. In your `com_mycom` directory there is a file called `mycom.php`. In it you have some lines that look like this:

```
$controller = JControllerLegacy::getInstance('Contact');
$controller->execute(JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('task'));
$controller->redirect();
```

See an example here:
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/components/com_contact/contact.php#L15

So that's what takes the task and instantiates an instance of that controller object, and pulls the task from the hidden form input value that you pointed out. It passes the task to the controller from there.

The controller receives the request here:

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/components/com_contact/controller.php#L19

You might be asking "why don't I see it receiving the task that the component file sends it?". Well that's because the controller for this component is a child-class of the JControllerLegacy class:

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/legacy/controller/legacy.php#L701

```
public function execute($task)
{ ... }
```

This function is the execute function which receives the task from the component. This is the parent class of your controller task. Hopefully this all makes sense!

Comment: Thanks for that Chad! Jobin Jose just beat you to it :)

Comment: Just so you know Jobin Jose's code is only applicable to Joomla 1.5. The files he referenced don't exist in Joomal 3.x:

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/tree/staging/libraries/joomla/application

Comment: @ChadWindnagle its not only for 1.5 its for upto 2.x

Comment: Good point Chad, my component is actually developed for Joomla 3.x but Jobin Jose's answer was enough to point me in the right direction. I think for the benefit of future readers I'll accept your answer as it is currently more relevant.

Comment: Good point Jobin Jose! I'd say either one is close enough to be honest.

Comment: @ChadWindnagle you are giving updated version answer thats Good +1!

Answer (score 3):

When you set the `controller` name explicitly with hidden fields

```
<input type="hidden" name="task" value="testctrl.save" />
```

or

```
<input type="hidden" name="controller" value="testctrl" />
<input type="hidden" name="task" value="save" />
```

or even not specifying the controller with task , just used it with view name.

All the cases your component file like `com_test` have a file with `test.php`

it includes Joomla library files.

```
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');
```

when you check the library file it have two function for getting related controller and models.

`createFileName()` and `getInstance()` in `libraries/joomla/application/component/controller.php`

These two function do the task.

The above files are applicable only for Joomla 1.5 to Joomla 2.x

**Edit**

For **Joomla3.x**

In Joomla 3. x The file structure little bit changed.

Instead of  `jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');` Joomla 3.x uses

```
$controller = JControllerLegacy::getInstance('Content');
```

This will call the `JControllerLegacy` class in `libraries\legacy\controller\legacy.php`

you can find the same functions `createFileName() ,getInstance()` on the above path.

Hope its helps..

Comment: Cool thanks! I was trying trace that but couldn't find it! That was really annoying me :)

Comment: Just for anyone else checking out this answer: this answer code is for Joomla 1.5. Joomla 3.x does not have that file at all.

Comment: I've accepted Chads answer instead for the benefit of future readers as it a more relevant answer going forward.

Comment: @doovers Updated as per J3.x version too.